# Comparing percentages of 10 different groups without access to the raw data

Tags: anova, nonparametric, percentage

I have access to the percentages of referring to "X" for 10 different ethnic groups. Let's say, A1 to A10 as shown below

A1: 9.22
A2: 11.40
A3: 12.68
A4: 17.89
A5: 19.53
A6: 19.84
A7: 29.34
A8: 30.77
A9: 32.56
A10:41.82

As clearly seen here there is a huge difference between A1 and A10 ethnic group in referring to "X". Is there any statistical test that can be used for testing whether there is a significant difference between the percentage within these 10 groups?
I do not have access to the raw data. I only have access to the number of participants of each ethnic group, and the frequency of referring to "X" that the percentages were calculated from. Please note that the sample size is not equal ranging from 52 for A10 to 2716 for A1.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chi-squared+test

Comment: @whuber Are you suggesting that the link you give us a duplicate or are you suggesting that a chi square test is an appropriate analysis.?  Keeping in mind that the OP is a new user it might help to give a little more guidance.

Comment: Thanks Michael and Whuber. More clarifications will be appreciated.

Comment: @whuber I think a logistic regression would be better.

Comment: @Student If you treat the groups as a 10-level factor and use ML to fit the logistic model, I believe the result will be equivalent to a chi-squared test.  Perhaps the main consideration would be accessibility: is it more effective to explain logistic regression or a chi-squared test to somebody who is completely new at this?  (I don't have a definite answer, because it might depend on availability of software, but it seems to me that logistic regression might require a bit more explanation and would produce a lot more output that requires clarification.)

Comment: Thank you all of for your suggestions. I have access to SPSS and know this software for quite a long time. I have also access to R and have used it only for one research project before. Regarding Chi square test, I have used it for other purposes when I had X rows and Y columns (X and Y greater equal two) but I am not sure how to use it in this case that I have  10 rows (different ethnic groups) and 1 column (percentage).

Comment: The out put using crosstabs with statistics in SPSS:Pearson Chi-Square: Value: 90.000 df: 81 Asymptotic Significance (2-sided): .231
Likelihood Ratio: Value  46.052 df    81 Asymptotic Significance (2-sided).999
Linear-by-Linear Association Value   5.739 df    1 Asymptotic Significance (2-sided).017
N of Valid Cases 10  
a 100 cells (100.0%) have expected count less than 5. The minimum expected count is .10.